# Saved table to Hive metastore with .saveAsTable(), how do I reload?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I used `.saveAsTable` on my DataFrame and now it is stored in my HDFS hive warehouse metastore. How can I load this back into Spark SQL? I have deleted my cluster (Azure HDInsight) and created a new one, confirmed my Hive metastore location is the same and the directory is still there.

I need to load this again as a persistent table, not as a temp table as I am using the PowerBI/Spark connector. The only way I have found to do so far is to load the directory back into a DF, then run .saveAsTable again.. which is writing the file again and takes a long time to process. I'm hopeful there is a better way!!

Answer (score 0):

After you use `.saveAsTable` you may query direcly with sql.

```
df.saveAsTable("tableName")
myOtherDf = sqlContext.sql("select * from tableName")
```

Comment: I'm aware - I have done that before. I have since deleted/recreated my cluster and now the table is no longer showing when I run `SHOW TABLES` or try and query it, but the Hive directory is still in my HDFS store and configured as the metastore location in Spark .